# How do I call this method from the Linux repo?

Tags: c, linux, hid

I've been trying for a while not to find a way to control the lights on a set of controllers from the game Buzz (wired, from Playstation 2). You can see some of my failed attempts in my questions over on Stack Overflow

- [Ruby libusb: Stall error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32573723/ruby-libusb-stall-error)
- [Sending HID defined messages with usblib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32618988/sending-hid-defined-messages-with-usblib)

So I turned to a more base linux method of sending messages, and failed to do it by piping data to /dev/hidraw0, too.

Then I discovered a file in the linux repository which refers to the buzz controllers specifically ([/linux/drivers/hid/hid-sony.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/hid/hid-sony.c)), and the fact that they have a light. It even has a method called buzz_set_leds (line 1512):

```
static void buzz_set_leds(struct sony_sc *sc)
```

So I'm 100% sure that this is the code does what I'm trying to do.

I've had a go at including this in a c file, but am unable to include hid-sony because I seem to be missing these files.

```
#include <linux/device.h>
#include <linux/hid.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <linux/leds.h>
#include <linux/power_supply.h>
#include <linux/spinlock.h>
#include <linux/list.h>
#include <linux/idr.h>
#include <linux/input/mt.h>

#include "hid-ids.h"
```

In compilation, I get this error:

```
hid-sony.c:29:26: fatal error: linux/device.h: No such file or directory
 #include <linux/device.h>
                          ^
compilation terminated.
```

Sorry, I'm a Ruby programmer with no background in C.

How do I get these missing 'linux/' files and refer to them from my c library?

Comment: `buzz_set_leds` is a static function, so it probably wouldn't be exported even if you have the headers. Also, programs generally don't link to the kernel itself, so trying to include kernel header files is probably wrong.

Comment: Perhaps I can simplify the question. How can I call this method?

Comment: That's a kernel driver. You will not be able to use that code in a user program at all. I haven't looked at the driver in detail. But in general, the Linux LED subsystem exposes LED functionality to user level via sysfs. Have a look at the contents of the `/sys/class/leds` directory and some references such as [this](http://fabiobaltieri.com/2011/09/21/linux-led-subsystem/) and [this](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/leds/leds-class.txt).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks a lot to @brian-malehorn, @alan-au and @colonel-thirty-two. I'm answering this myself because none of them told me the exact answer, but they lead me to it.

The answer to this specific question is "don't".

The underlying question is "how do I turn these lights on in Linux?" and this is how I did it.

In /sys/class/leds, when the controllers are plugged in, has these 4 folders in it (not actual folders, but expressed as folders in the file system).

```
0003:054C:0002.0007::buzz1
0003:054C:0002.0007::buzz2
0003:054C:0002.0007::buzz3
0003:054C:0002.0007::buzz4
```

The middle 2 hex numbers are elements of the device descriptor from lsusb

```
Bus 002 Device 011: ID 054c:0002 Sony Corp. Standard HUB
```

The last number appears to be an identifier for usb devices and instances when they've been plugged in. If I unplug this device and plug it back in, the last number increments.

I can't work out what the first one is just at the moment, but as a theory, it might be the HID interface class. This is from `lsusb -vd 054c:0002`

```
bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
```

Each of these folders contains a max_brightness 'file' which contains the number 1, and a brightness 'file' which can be used to control it.

I had to open the rights to these (this is a little clumsy, but this did it):

```
cd /sys/class/leds
sudo chmod 777 */brightness
```

I can then turn an led on like this:

```
echo 1 > 0003\:054C\:0002.0007\:\:buzz1/brightness
```

And turn off an LED like this:

```
echo 0 > 0003\:054C\:0002.0007\:\:buzz1/brightness
```

I can also bypass all those complicated changing numbers and escaping colons with this:

```
echo 1 > *buzz1/brightness
```

Comment: Good work! BTW, you can do pretty cool things through the Linux LED subsystem. For example, you can set "triggers" which flash the LED in certain ways in response to certain events. A simple example of a trigger is the "heartbeat" trigger. This will pulse the LED based on the load of your box. Other common triggers include flashing LEDs based on network activity, disk activity, etc.

Comment: It's a bit of a round-about way of doing it, but I want the buzzer light to turn on when someone pushes the buzzer, then turn off when I start a timer in my application... It's a long story. That should be easy now I can do this.

Comment: I really can't explain the various tech hells I've gone through this week trying to find this.

Comment: @alun_au do you happen to know if there's a file in /sys or /dev somewhere I can watch for the input from these controllers?

Comment: @AJFarafay The driver does look like it supports the Linux Input system. Which means you can watch for input events from that device by reading /dev/input/eventX. Where X varies depending on what devices you have on your system (there should also be a more descriptive symbolic link). Have a look at [this doc](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/input/input.txt).  A quick way to play around with the events is to use the [evtest](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/evtest.1.html) utility. If you encounter issues pls start a new question (too hard to answer in comments).

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, yes, I will start again next time I'm stuck.

Comment: It's not a question but I thought you'd like to know that I found my answer and wrapped it up in Ruby. https://github.com/AJFaraday/ruby-buzz

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that you can't just compile that file individually... it's meant to be built along with the whole Linux kernel. That code is only meant to be run by the kernel, not a user program. You want that code to run, but you need to figure out the proper way to call it (through a system call or something).

tl;dr: you're looking in the wrong place, you don't want kernel code

Comment: So, if I gather this correctly, not the hid-sony.c file, but the compiled code will be somewhere inside my linux distribution. So I need to find some linux utility or file which calls this kernel code. Is that correct?